# html input button default border css

Tags: html, forms, input, css

the submit input type, normally has a 'bevel' 3D on the side corner. how to use css to make it plain look?

Answer (score 4):

This should work for what you need:

```
 input 
 {
        border: 0;
 }
```

or if you wanted to be more specific:

```
 input[type=button], input[type=submit] 
 { 
        border: 0 
 }
```

or you could use an inline styling:

```
<input type=button value="Testing" style="border:0">
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding any kind of border to the button will remove the browsers built in '3D effect'. Something like the following will add a simple grey border instead.

```
input[type=submit] {
    border: 1px solid 333;
}
```

Note that the default button styling is dependant on both browser and operating system, so it is definitely worth applying your own styling if you want total control of the look of your page.

Comment: In fact the default styling for all HTML elements is defined by the W3C. That doesn't stop different browsers and OSs from doing things differently, but there is *supposed* to be at least some degree of conformity in the defaults.